# WooCommerce "Division By Zero" Error for Discount Percentage Text

Tags: woocommerce

I'm working on this code and while I've done my best to make it work, I cannot fix the "divided by zero" error that occurs on the archive (shop page) for grouped products.

This is the error message:
`Warning: Division by zero in`
That makes the percentage text show up like this: `Save: -$18 (-INF%)`

The error refers to this line:

```
$saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';
```

Here's the full code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'display_sale_price_and_percentage_html', 10, 2 );
function display_sale_price_and_percentage_html( $price, $product ) {

    // sale products on frontend excluding variable products
    if( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() && ! $product->is_type('variable')) {

    // product prices
    $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price(); // Regular price
    $sale_price = (float) $product->get_price();

    // price calculation and formatting
    $saving_price = wc_price( $regular_price - $sale_price );

    // percentage calculation and formatting
    $precision = 1; // decimals
    $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';

    // display the formatted html price including amount and precentage using a span tag which means displaying it on the same row, if you want this on a new row, change the tag into a paragraph
    $price .= sprintf( __('<span class="saved-sale"> Save: %s <em>(%s)</em></span>', 'woocommerce' ), $saving_price, $saving_percentage );
    }
return $price;
}
```

The error is shown on grouped products. It works fine on simple products. My goal is to make this work for all product types (simple, grouped, external and variable).

I need all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's because grouped products don't have a `$regular_price`. You should add some conditions to check if `$sale_price` and `$regular_price` are non-zero. You could also check that you aren't on a grouped product, but checking for 0 will also prevent divide by zero errors anywhere you have a free product.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'display_sale_price_and_percentage_html', 10, 2 );
function display_sale_price_and_percentage_html( $price, $product ) {

    // sale products on frontend excluding variable products
    if( $product->is_on_sale() && ! is_admin() && ! $product->is_type('variable')) {

        // product prices
        $regular_price = (float) $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price = (float) $product->get_price();

        if( $regular_price > 0 && $sale_price > 0 ) {
            // price calculation and formatting
            $saving_price = wc_price( $regular_price - $sale_price );

            // percentage calculation and formatting
            $precision = 1; // decimals
            $saving_percentage = round( 100 - ( $sale_price / $regular_price * 100 ), 1 ) . '%';

            // display the formatted html price including amount and precentage using a span tag which means displaying it on the same row, if you want this on a new row, change the tag into a paragraph
            $price .= sprintf( __('<span class="saved-sale"> Save: %s <em>(%s)</em></span>', 'your-textdomain' ), $saving_price, $saving_percentage );

        }
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: Nah, sometimes you just need fresh eyes to take a look. Glad it worked.